# tricked-out -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([Tiny wind- and solar-powered 'Ecocapsule' promises ultimate getaway](https://homes.yahoo.com/news/micro-living-wind-solar-powered-153438319.html)):

> It's as if science fiction and all the biggest tiny-living trends came together and laid an adorably **tricked-out egg**: Behold the Ecocapsule, a self-sustaining, low-energy, portable dwelling that allows users to live off-grid anywhere in the world (that gets at least a decent amount of sunlight).

What does that actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is "tricked out", someone has put a lot of time (and probably money), into adding cool features and designs to it. Usually I think of cars when I hear this. A tricked-out vehicle is one that has been painted and heavily customized with special parts you don't find on normal cars.

[image: Tricked-out truck]

These little egg-shaped homes have also been very carefully designed to contain a lot of awesome features. They are cool and trendy (to a certain kind of person, at least).

Answer (score 3):

It is a combination of the metaphor of *laying an egg* and the expression *tricked-out*.

*Tricked-out* means *decorated/made in such a way that it attracts people's attention*.

*They laid an egg* here simply means *together they created...*

So the Ecocapsule looks as if it is something that has been created by combining science-fiction with all the biggest  tiny-living trends. Furthermore, it has a sort of flair or maybe even extravagance, it catches the eye.